# In arc what happens when you don't synthesize

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

In an iOS ARC enabled project, what happens when I don't synthesize a property, since retain/release are disallowed?

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray*     _pieces;
}
@end
```

What are the memory semantics of the iVar _pieces in this case?
Say I set it using, `_pieces = whatever`.

Is _pieces set to nil when the instance of my SomeClass is deallocated?
Is _pieces stored as a weak reference?
If all other objects that have retained _pieces release it, will it be null when I attempt to access it?

Comment: Why was this marked down, it seems like a very valid useful question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple of observations, much of which is probably clear by this point based upon the feedback of others:

1. You synthesize properties, not instance variables, and in your example, you showed us an example of an instance variable, not a property.
2. Your question might imply some assumed connection between synthesizing and the ability to do `retain`/`release`, but there is no such connection. The ability to do `retain` and `release` is a function of whether you are using [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) or not. It has nothing to do with synthesizing properties.
3. As others have observed, explicitly declared instance variables, such as your example, are `strong` references, by default. So, in your example, `_pieces` is a `strong` reference.
4. Yes, when your `SomeClass` object is deallocated, it will remove its `strong` reference to the `_pieces` object. Obviously, if that's the last strong reference to the object pointed to by `_pieces` it will be deallocated and any other `weak` references you have to it elsewhere will be set to `nil`. For a more complete discussion on the memory management, see Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).
5. You asked "If all other objects that have retained `_pieces` release it, will it be `nil` when I attempt to access it?" Obviously that would be true if `_pieces` was a `weak` reference, but given that it's implicitly a `strong` reference in `SomeClass`, no, that is not the case.
6. If you wanted to make `pieces` a [declared property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html), the syntax would be 
    
   `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* pieces;`
   The designation of `strong` vs. `weak` (or whatever) dictates the memory management of the property.
7. If you declare a property, you not only no longer have to explicitly define the instance variable, but rather it is now advised that you really should not do so (because when it's synthesized, the compiler will create the ivar for you). But, if you happen to have an explicitly declared instance variable of the right name for your property, the compiler will use that for the property. But that's not only unnecessary, but also inadvisable (because if you mistype the name of the instance variable, you may unwittingly end up with two instance variables). Just let the compiler synthesize your instance variables for your properties and this potential ambiguity goes away.
8. The name of the instance variable that will be synthesized for a property is governed by the syntax of the [property implementation directive](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9), i.e. the `@synthesize` statement. Thus, if you have a `@synthesize` statement for your `pieces` property of the form:
   `@synthesize pieces;`
   then the instance variable will be called `pieces`. But if you use the preferred `@synthesize` syntax of:
   `@synthesize pieces = _pieces;`
   then the instance variable name will have the preceeding underscore (which is, by convention, preferred, to avoid ambiguity in your code between properties and instance variables). And, as of Xcode 4.4, if you omit the `@synthesize` statement for a `@property`, it will implicitly synthesize it for you with the latter syntax, i.e. the instance variable will bear the leading underscore).

Comment: Is it a good assumption to assume @synthesize properties are for public variables, and iVar for variables outside classes shouldn't care about?

Comment: @1dayitwillmake You certainly want to [declare public properties for exposed data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW4) (i.e. your "public variables") in your .h file. Personally, I put my private ivars and properties in a [private class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3) in the .m file.

Comment: @1dayitwillmake Whether that private data is stored as ivars or as properties is a matter of personal preference (I generally use ivars, but understand why people use private properties, but I'm driven by pragmatic considerations, not religious fervor). Also, note you can [limit the scope](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127) of your ivars in the .h file (e.g. using the `@private` directive), but I think it's cleaner to put that private stuff in the class extension.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that you've not created a property that uses this, which overrides the assumed behaviour**, instance variables in ARC projects are assumed strong, so the declaration really is

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    __strong NSMutableArray* _pieces;
}
@end
```

So, in answer to your questions

> Is _pieces set to nil when the instance of my SomeClass is deallocated?

No, but assigning an instance to it won't cause it to be deallocated.

> Is _pieces stored as a weak reference?

No, it is a strong reference.

> If all other objects that have retained _pieces release it, will it be null when I attempt to access it?

No, this is the same question as your first one.

Comment: How do I 'release' the reference then to allow it to be deallocated

Comment: Well, change what `_pieces` refers to. It's the object referenced by the variable that gets deallocated, and the object keeps track of what is referencing it (its retain count). If a strong variable is referencing an object, the retain count is incremented. If the object is no longer referenced by a particular variable, the retain count is decreased. Once the retain count is 0, it can be deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you declaring a property named `pieces` or is this a straight ivar?

If you define a property then the memory usage depends on how you define the property.

If this is a straight ivar then by default the ivar will be `strong`. This essentially means the ivar will properly retain and release what ever object you assign to it. You can safely use it without worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, ARC will treat it as you would treat it in a manner similar to `strong`. When you assign to it, the incoming value will be `retain`ed and the value no longer pointed to will be `release`d. It will only dangle if it somehow becomes over released. If you have a property declaration, ARC will abide by the rules specified there, and the accessors will be automatically synthesized for you in the form `@synthesize someObject = _someObject`. When the object gets deallocated, I presume the object gets sent `release` so that if nothing else has asserted ownership, the object pointed to by the pointer will also be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

with the new runtime you only need @properties btw - dont declare ivars, dont synthesize

Comment: This assumes he wants a property. It is perfectly fine to have an ivar with no property.

Comment: If I don't synthesize it gives an error: Auto property synthesis is synthesizing property not explicitly synthesized