# what does "_object" mean in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

```
@property (nonatomic, copy ) NSString *title;
@synthesize title = _title;
```

what does this '_title' mean?

Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297829/in-arc-what-happens-when-you-dont-synthesize

Comment: Here are answers posted before.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the backing iVar for the property has a leading underscore.

So you can use property syntax to access it:

```
self.title = @"Some title";
```

or you access it directly, but using the underscore name

```
_title = @"Some title";
```

Although using direct access is discouraged except for initialisers and the dealloc method.

If you are using auto synthesis, the underscore is added by default.

The reason for this:

It makes it a lot clearer when you are using direct access to refer to an iVar rather than a local variable, or a property.

It also means that you can use obvious names for method parameters and not worry about them clashing; for example, if you were to write a method that referred to the property:

Answer (score 3):

`_title` is **iVar.** mean it is variable and title just is a property.You are synthesizing by assigning iVar to property.Because you need not write the methods like

```
- (NSString *)title {
    return _title;
}

- (void)settitke:(int)newValue {
    _title = newValue;
}
```

Those are getter and setters

when you do

`title =_title`.Those two above methods will abstract the setter and getter in one line.